# $_POST is returning just 'Array' as string and i am posting an Array

Tags: php, post, request

It's a very strange error that i am facing.I have some html i.e below

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="om[1]" value="10">
<input type="checkbox"  name="om[2]" value="20">
<input type="checkbox"  name="om[3]" value="30">
```

When i post this form and do

```
print_r($_POST['om'])
it gives just prints 'Array' as string
and if i do print_r($_POST['om'][0]) it gives A
and if i do print_r($_POST['om'][1]) it gives r
```

But if i do

```
print_r($_REQUEST['om'])
it display a proper array

Array
   (
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 20
    [3] => 30
  )
```

Problem is when i am using **$_POST** for getting array values it not displaying, it works fine if posted value is not in array.
But i can get all the required result with **$_REQUEST['om']** even if they are array.

And it's happening only on **server**, working fine for localhost.
Can anybody tell what can be the problem on server??

Comment: Try `name="om[]"` on each (without keys)

Comment: Try $om = $_POST['om'] then access the indices. I think that the print_r is confusing you.

Comment: @FDL there is nothing wrong with providing keys

Comment: @FDL  i don't think it has to do anything with keys, because it was runing well for 3 months, suddenly yesterday problem comes

Comment: @sandeepKumar can you show your form tag

Comment: @FDL debugging without keys against what known php bug?

Comment: @FDL well i have tried that also without keys, same result

Comment: Show us your exact code, not your pseudo-descriptive one. That includes the actual `<form>` tag.

Comment: What has changed when it stopped working? A new PHP version, server reconfiguration, ...? Can you post your [`variables_order`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order) and [`request_order`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.request-order) settings from the server? (You can use [`ini_get()`](http://be2.php.net/ini_get) to read them if you don't have direct configuration access.)

Comment: If it has been working for months and suddenly stopped, the question "what has changed on the host ?" is worth answering.

Comment: If you have a bad filtering thing, that would do it. Are you using some sort of framework/CMS/whatever?

Comment: Can you look at the data being sent via firebug or similar? Does the form set the encoding?

Comment: @minitech yes i am using codeigniter

Comment: @OwenBeresford yes i have checked with firebug, as i was sending data with ajax request with serializing the form

Comment: Have you got raw_post turned on, and what does that hold?  Either fopen('php://input') or $HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA.
See other peoples notes here http://getluky.net/2009/02/24/php-_post-array-empty-although-phpinput-and-raw-post-data-is-available/

Comment: use **method="post"** i think this one is not mention in your form. If you are not use post method then the $_POST will not working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is put your **magic_quotes_gpc = off** in php.ini file

Answer (score 2):

This is just explanation, I tested this:

```
<pre>
<form method="post">
<input type="checkbox"  name="om[1]" value="10">
<input type="checkbox"  name="om[2]" value="20">
<input type="checkbox"  name="om[3]" value="30">
<input type="submit">
<?php
print_r($_POST['om'][1]);
print_r($_POST['om'][2]);
print_r($_POST['om'][3]);

print_r($_REQUEST['om']);
?>
```

Output:

```
10
20
30
Array
(
    [1] => 10
    [2] => 20
    [3] => 30
)
```

Comment: it's runing good for me on my server earlier also,it's just i think server problem that those values which are in array not able to access it with $_POST but can access with $_REQUEST

Comment: @sandeepKumar you should copy/paste the above test code in a PHP file on your server, to see if the same behavior occurs. This way you will be able to tell if it is a server/vhost level issue, or something in your PHP stack.

Answer (score 2):

> Can anybody tell what can be the problem on server?

Most likely your own can because you has access to it and you can trouble-shoot it.

From what you describe, on your server `$_POST['om']` is the string  `"Array"`. Period.

How it has become that is not visible from the code you've posted in your question, only that it is.

BTW, the string `"Array"` is also a sign that on the server you (probably by accident) have placed code and configuration that casts an array to a string (http://php.net/language.types.type-juggling).

A modern PHP version will notice you about such btw. So first thing you should do is enable error logging on the server and set the verbosity to the highest level so that you can see warnings, notices and strict warnings in the PHP error log. Then follow the error log and look for array conversion notices.

If that does not lead you to anything, you need to get a step-debugger in your hands and do some remote debugging so to verify that your expectations are met and where they get broken. That normally is the the fastest way to find out what happens as you can inspect the program while it runs.

Comment: i have faced this fatal error on my server  PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 94371840 bytes , then i have did this ini_set('memory_limit', '-1'), leaving this nothing has changed on server

Comment: Well the memory consumption is a sign that you hit some boundary. I would further try to understand why you hit the memory limit. disabling memory limit only hides the error but does not stop the cause. so it removes the symptom only.

Comment: you are absolutely right,but when i see the fatal error in error log, i found this solution only for that moment to keep running server, can you please suggest what's wrong with $_POST, it's givng values if the post value is not an array , but when it's a arryay it's just returning a string "Array"

Comment: You need to *trouble-shoot* the issue. I can't tell you because I can not reproduce it nor do I have access to the code nor server. You probably need to find someone you can go through your issue so you've got a fresh pair of eyes? Nobody there where you are who can help you?

Comment: i have tried with all then only i posted on stackoverflow,anyways thank you for your precious time :)

Answer (score 1):

If you try to `print_r` an `Array`, it'll return `Array`. Most data types in PHP are like this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure that

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="om[1]" value="10">
```

is not the same as

```
$_POST['om'][1]
```

The one in the form is an array with a string-type index "1", while in the $_POST var you're accessing the first element of $_POST['om'].

So you'll either have to use something else than integers in the HTML form or access the values by using `$_POST['om']['1']`.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.print-r.php
prints string "Array" only if the parameter is string, so I guess the $_POST superglobal was overridden before the print_r line (which is also proven by the fact that the $_RESQUEST suberglobal contains the original and expected value) 
try to var_export it

Answer (score 0):

name="om[]"- remove the keys and try it's working for me.

```
    <pre>
    <form method="post">
    <input type="checkbox"  name="om[]" value="10">
    <input type="checkbox"  name="om[]" value="20">
    <input type="checkbox"  name="om[]" value="30">
    <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <?php
    print_r($_POST['om']);
    print_r($_REQUEST['om']);
    ?>
```

Output:

```
    Array
     (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 20
        [2] => 30
     )

    Array
     (
        [0] => 10
        [1] => 20
        [2] => 30
     )
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like `$_POST['om']` has been converted to a string accidentally. Like `print_r($_POST['om'] . "")` Missing debug statements?

I think the problem lies somewhere in a piece of code that you're not showing here. Nevertheless, you should use [var_dump](http://php.net/manual/de/function.var-dump.php) more often to analyse variables.

Answer (score 0):

Hello i have checked above your code.
It working fine. I think you are missing the form submit method

Please use **method="post"**

You can use indexing array like om[1],om[2],om[3] it doesn't matter.

Here is code:

```
<form method="post">
 <input type="checkbox"  name="om[1]" value="10">
 <input type="checkbox"  name="om[2]" value="20">
 <input type="checkbox"  name="om[3]" value="30">
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
</form>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
  //print_r($_REQUEST['om']);
  print_r($_POST['om']);
}
?>
```

Please check this code.

Comment: If he does not have a method="post" - would be an empty array $_POST

Comment: Yes you does not have a **method="post"** then form taken **method="get"** by default. please mention method="post" attribute in form tag. If you not add attribute method="post" then the $_POST not working. It will $_GET or $_REQUEST

Answer (score 0):

Checkboxes , Check them and you will get your values

```
<input type="checkbox"  name="om[1]" value="10" checked="true">
<input type="checkbox"  name="om[2]" value="20" checked="true">
<input type="checkbox"  name="om[3]" value="30" checked="true">
```

When a form is submitted, only "on" checkbox controls can become successful. [From the spec (4.01)](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.2.1)

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to pass array in $_POST using curl and on dumping, it was showing "Array" of type string to me. I found this question while looking for a solution. I hope this works out for your problem. The solution is to create a single array of parameters and then pass it as query as follows:

```
$aPostArray['aMyArray']=$aMyArray;

$sFieldString = http_build_query($aPostArray);
```

and then set it as

```
curl_setopt($ch1, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$sFieldString);
```